# Can't check or uncheck checkboxes in react if I initialize checked

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm building a react app with some checkbox inputs, and if I set checked to an initial value when I create my checkboxes, I can't check or uncheck them on the page. Does any one know what might be going on, or how to fix this? Thanks.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="reportFlags" value="fraud" checked={reportFlags[0]}/>Fraud </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `reportFlags` is an array, and it can have value like `.[ "fraud", ..]`. In this case, it should be written as:

```
<label>
  <inut
    type="checkbox"
    name="reportFlags"
    value="fraud"
    checked={reportFlags[0] === "fraud"}
  />Fraud{" "}
</label>
```

`checked` props should have a Boolean value `true` or `false`.. If you keep some truthy value like `checked={"fraud"}` for example, you can never uncheck it.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="reportFlags"
          value="fraud"
          checked={"fraud"}
        />Always checked
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add an onClick for your input

`<label><input type="checkbox" name="reportFlags" value="fraud" checked={reportFlags[0]} onClick={e=>{reportFlags[0] = e.checked}}/>Fraud </label>`